# Adding Links to HTML-output in Powershell

Tags: html, iis-7, powershell, wmi

I have wrote a PowerShell script that catches all of the running IIS worker processes on a remote server and returns back diagnostic information (appppolname, cpu, virtual memory etc). It is then converted to HTML and displayed to the user.

```
$server = Read-Host Enter server name...

if (!(test-connection -computername $server -quiet))
{ 
Write-Host $server is not pingable, does not exist, or timed out. Please try a different server.
}

else 
{
$command = 
{add-pssnapin WebAdministration

function get-iiswp([string]$name="*")
{

   $list = get-process w3wp -ea SilentlyContinue
   if ($error)
   {

Write-Host There are no IIS worker processes currently running. Error Message: $error

   }
        else
        {
            foreach($p in $list)
                { 
                $filter = "Handle='" + $p.Id + "'"
                $wmip = get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter $filter 

                if($wmip.CommandLine -match "-ap `"(.+)`"")
                    {
                        $appName = $matches[1]
                        $p | add-member NoteProperty AppPoolName $appName
                    }
                }
    $list | where { $_.AppPoolName -like $name }
    }
}

get-iiswp | select-object -property *
}


invoke-command -computername $server -scriptblock $command | ConvertTo-HTML ID, AppPoolName, @{Label="CPU(s)";Expression={if ($_.CPU -ne $()) {$_.CPU.ToString("N")}}}, @{Label="Virtual Memory";Expression={[int]($_.VM/1MB)}}, @{Label="Physical Memory";Expression={[int]($_.WS/1024)}} | Out-file D:/test.html

}
```

I am looking for a way to format the HTML-output to convert the AppPoolName output of the table into a link where it would use the AppPoolName and PID within the link itself (ex. http://powershell.com/requests.ps1x?PID=$PID&AppPoolName=$AppPoolName

If any one has any thoughts or ideas that could solve and point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

-----------Update-------------------

Here is the example output:

```
<tr><tr><tr>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
</head><body>
<h2>IIS Worker Process Diagnostic</h2>
<table>
<colgroup>
<col/>
<col/>
<col/>
<col/>
<col/>
</colgroup>
<tr><th>ID</th><th>AppPoolName</th><th>CPU(s)</th><th>Virtual Memory</th><th>Physical Memory</th></tr>
<tr><td>3820</td><td>AppPool1</td><td>4.92</td><td>355</td><td>74200</td></tr>
<tr><td>4108</td><td>AppPool2</td><td>0.23</td><td>106</td><td>21380</td></tr>
<tr><td>4940</td><td>AppPool3</td><td>0.20</td><td>590</td><td>39444</td></tr>
<tr><td>7244</td><td>AppPool4</td><td>0.33</td><td>596</td><td>42556</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could replace the AppPoolName (in ConvertTo-HTML) with this...

```
@{Label="AppPoolName";Expression={ '<a href="http://powershell.com/requests.ps1x?PID=$($_.PID)&AppPoolName=$($_.AppPoolName)">$($_.AppPoolName)</a>' }}
```

That's just off the top of me head and not tested... :-)

Comment: Hypothetically, you would think that would work. Given this script is executed in the PowerShell ASP (PS1X) it requires you to insert HTML with %> and <%. When I input the HTML link within this parameter it returns the link (although correct) above the HTML converted table.

Comment: think i understand - could you post examples of script and output?